# How to print a string randomly from cell string in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, printing, cell

Create a cell Array

```
d = {'good', 'job'};
```

Pick a random string to print.

Answer (score 1):

```
randomString = d{ceil(numel(d)*rand)};
```

Or, if your Matlab is recent enough to have the `randi` function:

```
randomString = d{randi(numel(d))};
```

Then print the string with `disp`, `fprintf` or whichever you use:

```
disp(randomString)
fprintf(fid, '%s', randomString);
```